# How to publish ChromeDriver.exe to drop location when using Floating Version (*) in project file (.csproj)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nuget-package

Trying to have the latest version of ChromeDriver without having to always update the Nuget: Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver in drop folder.

For this we used the floating variable: "*" for version as below in my project .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="*"/>
```

or

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver">
  <Version>*</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

This works in local wherein on build, the latest version of available chromedriver ( currently: 99.0.4844.5100 ) is installed into local machine in bin/debug (or whichever)

but using a floating variable doesn't copy the latest ChromeDriver.exe (or any version of ChromeDriver.exe) into the build drop when checked-in (whereas when the version is hardcoded or anything other than *, its copied to build drop upon check-in).

Any other way of using floating variable works: For example:

1. using 99* works (but this will always fix it to any version starting with 99, and will not get the next highest version when the next version 100 will release
2. using []/(]/()/[) works but again will not get the highest acceptable stable version
3. hardcoding the version like 99.0.4844.5100 works

Note: My goal is to

1. Not manually keep updating Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver in my projects
2. Have latest publish to build drop folder upon checkin
3. Copy build files to a remote VM X
4. Use the latest ChromeDriver.exe copied onto the machine X to run Selenium Test Cases using latest Nuget without manually and continuously checking and updating Nuget SeleniumWebDriver.ChromeDriver for a new version.

How can we move latest highest version of chromedriver.exe to build drop upon check-in without having to manually regularly updating the Nuget package: Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver ? (preferebly by using * in version of csproj) ?

Answer (score 1):

You may not reference `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` directly.
You may reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.1.0" />
```

and any version of chrome driver will be available for you without the need to update the `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` package version.

To update the driver binary on your machine to the latest version - you may use https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net